# how to find the variable which is empty and display it

Tags: javascript, html

I have three variable a,b and c in JavaScript and one of them is null. How do I find which one it is and then display it without if statements as I could have not 3 but even 300 variables. I tried to use a loop but with no luck. Thanks in Advance.
My code uses a array it is;

```
var x = [a,b,c];
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if (x[0] == null){
        alert(x[0]);
    }
}
```

However this only checks for null items but can't display them.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried ?

Comment: Use an array. If you don't, you will have to keep track of all these dynamic variables.

Comment: Are they a property of the same object?

Comment: In response to your edit: how can you display a null item if it's null..?

Comment: Yeah I want to create a simple physics equation solver when for example in a form time and speed will be provided by the user and the distance will remain null. if I know which value is null, i can then calculate it with a simple d = s* t formula and display it to the user.

Comment: just change `x[0]` to `x[i]`

Comment: @Lifecube - that's [what I said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22020120/665261) :)

Comment: you want to use an associative array and have it output the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var x = ['a', 'b', null];
    var i = x.indexOf(null);
    alert(i);
```

It works with vars:

```
    var a = 'foo';
    var b = 'bar';
    var c = null;
    var x = [a, b, c];
    var i = x.indexOf(null);
    alert(i);
```

Comment: That's just an array, not an array of variables

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the variables in an array and iterate over each element and check if it is null:

```
var arr = [];
var obj1 = 'davies';
var obj2 = 'darren';
var obj3 = null;

arr.push(obj1);
arr.push(obj2);
arr.push(obj3);

for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == null) {
       alert("index " + i + " is null");   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75Xwh/

Answer (score 0):

## **Using arrays:**

As somone suggested you can use an array, storing the values like so:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

You can access the values like so:

```
values[0]; // equals 1
values[3]; // equals 4
```

And loop through them like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log(values[i]);
}

Outputs:
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

## **Using objects:**

If it were me, though, I would use an object instead that way you can reference the object values by names (properties) instead of just by index. Of course, objects aren't the right tool for every job, but based on your vague description, it sounds like what you will need.

Create an object like so:

```
var someObj = {
    firstValue: 1,
    secondValue: 2,
    anotherValue: 3
};
```

Values can be accessed like so:

```
someObj.firstValue; // equals 1
```

or:

```
someObj['anotherValue']; // equals 3
```

And can be looped through like so:

```
for(var ind in someObj) {
    console.log(someObj[ind]);
}

Outputs:
    1
    2
    3
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can't use arrays or objects for some strange reason..

```
function findNull(){
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length;i++){
        if (arguments[i]===null) {
           return i;
        }
    }
}
```

if you call it like this:

```
findNull(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

and d is null and you know you only have one null it will return 3, since that's the index it was sent.

EDIT:

in response to your edit:

try

```
x = {"a":a; "b":b; "c":c};
// you can add more values like this
x["d"]=d;
for (var i in x){
    if (x[i]===null){
       alert (i);
    }
}
```

it will alert the name of the key (if b is null it will prompt b)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure exactly what you are looking for - but perhaps it is this...

```
var x = [a,b,c];
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    // reference the `i`th item rather than the 0th item each time
    if (x[i] == null){
        alert(x[i]);
    }
}
```

perhaps you are trying to avoid...

```
if (x[0] == null){
    alert(x[0]);
}
if (x[1] == null){
    alert(x[1]);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you should be using properties of an object rather than local variables in an array.

```
var x = {
    a: 23,
    b: null,
    c: 26
}

// your code can work with these values by doing 
// e.g. x.a++ instead of a++

for (var key in x) {
    if (x[key] === null) {
        alert(key);
    }
}
```